# Memory leak when calculating a determinant of a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, memory-leaks

While writing some code to calculate the determinant of a simple 3 x 3 matrix, I noticed that it started to accumulate memory leaks. I've reduced the method to the following (meaning that I do no longer use an algorithm to determine the size of any matrix, I do it "by hand"):

```
double Determinant(double** &m)
{
    return m[0][0] * (m[1][1] * m[2][2] - m[2][1] * m[1][2]) -
           m[0][1] * (m[1][0] * m[2][2] - m[1][2] * m[2][0]) +
           m[0][2] * (m[1][0] * m[2][1] - m[1][1] * m[2][0]);
}
```

I can't find a problem with this, since I do not allocate any memory inside the method. if I change it and simply return a double (`return 1.0`, for example) the leak is gone. What is happening here?

Edit (more code):

```
double LogMultivariateNormalDensity(unsigned char* &x, unsigned char* &mean, double** &sigma)
{
    double det = Determinant(sigma);
    ...
}
```

Which in turn is called inside a loop

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    LogMultivariateNormalDensity(_x[i], _mean[i], _sigma[i])
}
```

Being a 2d array, `_sigma` is allocated using `malloc` (in both dimensions).

Comment: what is the `unsigned int n` for?

Comment: There's no memory leak in the code you've posted. However, there may be one in the code that calls this function -- if the compiler is able to inline this function when it's replaced by a dummy implementation, perhaps the code that causes the leak was simply optimized out. Or perhaps there's code that leaks which is only called conditionally depending on the determinant value, and is not called with the dummy value. Either way, we need more context to help.

Comment: There isn't a memory leak in your function. Please post more code - the issue is probably related to the code that calls this function.

Comment: is `m` deleted after use? Is every subarray of `m` property deleted after use?

Comment: You can't have reduced *the whole thing* to that, as that doesn't even have a `main`.

Comment: @pvoosten, the unsigned int n was not used, I've removed it from the code, sorry.

Comment: @molbdnilo, with the "thing" I meant the function.

Comment: @Cameron, interesting, I'll have a closer look at it tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Same question again: where is the memory allocated with malloc released with free? (I first assumed you used new/delete)

Comment: @pvoosten, very interesting, since it was a simple 3x3 matrix I thought who cares to free it, it doesn't use that much memory, let's free it up when I finish the class with everything else I might add. Now that i free it up, the leak is gone. How comes that a class member, I only allocate once, creates a memory leak when accessed? Again: I only allocated the memory one time, and the leak manifested itself when I accessed the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory allocated with `malloc` must be freed with `free`. Always, even for a small amount of memory.

Comment: This I know, but why does it expand when I simply access it?

Comment: Maybe due to compiler optimizations. You could turn off all optimizations to see the difference.